# Filtering a json array based on a list of values

Tags: json, typescript, filtering

I am new to typescript in angular 2 and i stuck with a situation.
I have a json array in this format

```
needle json 
[{"empId":100,"orgId":500}
{"empId":201,"orgId":566}]
```

The above json is in a particular order and we need to keep that order maintained while looking for those in another json array(Haystack)

```
Haystack json array
[
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Ashish","Lname":"Shukla"},
{"empCode":22,"fname":"John","Lname":"Mark"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Vigil","Lname":"Rocker"},
{"empCode":201,"fname":"Rick","Lname":"Mandez"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Erik","Lname":"Francis"},
{"empCode":100,"fname":"Alex","Lname":"Mishra"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Feeder","Lname":"Kapoor"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Dan","Lname":"Rox"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Herb","Lname":"Deen"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Nate","Lname":"Diaz"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Nick","Lname":"Diaz"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Conor","Lname":"Pussy"}
]
```

Now i need to get those values from haystack array whose id matches in needle keeping the order maintained of the  needle

```
{"empCode":100,"fname":"Alex","Lname":"Mishra"},
{"empCode":201,"fname":"Rick","Lname":"Mandez"}
```

I have achieved the solution to this problem but i guess my solution is not optimal as i am using many loops. Can some one suggest me a good solution.

PLS NOTE: Order of the employee id should be maintained in result json as of the needle json.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Add your current solution

Comment: Yes I have a solution but that's not optimal. I create a array of the needle keeping the ids. Now I iterate the haystack array and do a index of see if that is present in the new array. To keep the order alive I put the value in a map as Id, row count. I know that's not the optimal solution hence posted it.

Comment: Im not asking you if its optimal or not, just add it!

Comment: So? Where is your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
public needle: any;
public hayStack: any;

this.needle = [
{"empId": 100, "orgId": 500},
{"empId": 201, "orgId": 566}
];

this.hayStack = [
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Ashish","Lname":"Shukla"},
{"empCode":22,"fname":"John","Lname":"Mark"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Vigil","Lname":"Rocker"},
{"empCode":201,"fname":"Rick","Lname":"Mandez"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Erik","Lname":"Francis"},
{"empCode":100,"fname":"Alex","Lname":"Mishra"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Feeder","Lname":"Kapoor"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Dan","Lname":"Rox"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Herb","Lname":"Deen"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Nate","Lname":"Diaz"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Nick","Lname":"Diaz"},
{"empCode":21,"fname":"Conor","Lname":"Pussy"}
];

const needleEmpId = this.needle.map(item => item.empId);
const hayStackEmpCode = this.hayStack.map(item => item.empCode);

const result = hayStackEmpCode.map((id, index) => {
if (needleEmpId.indexOf(id) != -1) {
  return this.hayStack[index];
}
}).sort().filter(item => (item != undefined));

console.log(result);
```

Result

`0:{empCode: 100, fname: "Alex", Lname: "Mishra"}`

`1:{empCode: 201, fname: "Rick", Lname: "Mandez"}`

Comment: Thanks for your comment I will check and update tomorrow morning its too late to evaluate right now in ist. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I tried using your solution, but the result is comming out to be empty :(
 When i displayed value of needleEmpId and hayStackEmpCode  those are correct but the result is empty.

Comment: if (needleEmpId.indexOf(id) != -1) {
console.log("matched");
  return this.hayStack[index];
}
match never happens it hard to understand why :(

Comment: Did you assign the correct names to the array? Are you sure you are not missing anything? All of this code goes inside the constructor except the first 2 lines where variables are defined, they are outside constructor, did you add it to the constructor?  This is a working code(I pasted the console result intentionally). I will try to create a working plnk link for this.

Comment: Yea i tried as it is. It's never going inside the condition. I printed the ID and index both are coming correct but the match never happens :-(

Comment: Can you show your complete code? I can possibly take a look and see what's wrong with it.

Comment: sure will do that today.. sorry was away for few days hence could not rply